# CosmosDB: How to iterate over all documents from query in stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I want to process documents in a stored procedure, how can I get them as javascript objects.

What I tried so far is the simplest query of just getting all documents using the following stored procedure:

```
function sample(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM root r',
        function (err, feed1, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Try to get all documents to model further processing in javascript.
            var isAccepted2 = collection.queryDocuments(
                collection.getSelfLink(),
                'SELECT * FROM root r',
                { maxItemCount: -1, pageSize: -1, enableCrossPartitionQuery: true },
                function (err, feed2, options) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    getContext().getResponse().setBody(
                        "feed1[0]: " + JSON.stringify(feed1[0]) +
                        ", feed2.length: " + feed2.length);
                });
        });
}
```

My first idea was that `feed2.length` would reflect the total number of documents for that query enabling me to iterate over the `feed2` like an array, but this is not the case since this stored procedure returns the following output:

```
feed1[0]: {"$1":8440}, feed2.length: 2791
```

My interpretation of the first querys result is that the document count is 8440. How can I iterate over those in the stored procedure javascript?

Comment: `enableCrossPartitionQuery` doesn't make sense inside of a sproc because a sproc can only see the data of one partition. Could it be that you have more than one partition?

Comment: But your idea is valid. You can iterate over feed2. However, you still need to check that their is no continuation token and then you need to deal with the possibility that the sproc will be terminated prematurely by exceeding resources. You do this by seeing if isAccepted2 is false, returning out of the sproc with and indication that it needs to be restarted and where to pick back up. Here is the pattern I use for writing sprocs so they pick up where I left off: https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils#pattern-for-writing-stored-procedures

Comment: Note, in production, you would not want to do the first count query because it eats into the time your sproc has available to run.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone, thank you for the pointers. I will take a look at cosmos db documentation again to see if I can find an answer, guided by your ideas. I have not yet found a way to measure if there is more than one partition (that might become another question)

Comment: @LarryMaccherone, I was unable to find indication that `a sproc can only see the data of one partition` in documentation from Microsoft. Where is this idea coming from? Can you point me to a source?